# How to give multiple static ip in apache ignite cache configuration xml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ignite

I'm using Spring Boot microservice integrated with apache ignite to store the key and some value for it in cache.

In the ignite cache configuration file I'm trying to share my cache across 4 servers with same port i.e.,I should able to fetch but couldn't share the cache across 4 but it is picking only 2 servers for clustering, In other servers it ignite cache is started as a separate one and it is not into the cluster. Please help on this.

Do i need to do any other configuration changes to cluster 4 servers.

`Cacheconfig.xml`:

```
<property name="discoverySpi">
  <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
    <property name="ipFinder">
      <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
        <property name="addresses">
          <list>
            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
            <!-- <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value> -->
            <value>158.xxx.xx.xxx</value><!--server1 ip-->
            <value>158.xxx.xx.xxx</value><!--server2 ip-->
            <value>158.xxx.xx.xxx</value><!--server3 ip-->
            <value>4444</value><!--my port-->
          </list>
        </property>
      </bean>
    </property>
  </bean>
</property>
```

Here I have replaced the default IP address with the actual server IP address required.

But I could see when I give this way `<value>158.xxx.xx.xxx:4444..158.xxx.xx.xxx:4444</value>` it worked for sharing between 2 servers.

This will not work when it has more than 2 server IP addresses to be added to the list.

Please help in sharing cache for more than 3 servers.

Below is code i m using for starting the ignite and activate the cluster

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteException;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class IgniteCacheManager {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(IgniteCacheManager.class); 
    private  Ignite ignite;
    public Ignite getIgnite() {
        return ignite;
    }
    @Autowired
    private IgniteCacheManager(AppSpecificIgniteProperties igniteProperties) {
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        Enumeration<Object> keys = p.keys();
        LOGGER.debug("-----------------------------SYSTEM PROPERTIES Start--------------------------------------");
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String) keys.nextElement();
            String value = (String) p.get(key);
            LOGGER.info(key);
            LOGGER.info(value);
        }
        LOGGER.debug("-----------------------------SYSTEM PROPERTIES End--------------------------------------");
        try {

            // Ignite cache will start
            ignite=Ignition.start(igniteProperties.getConfigFile());            
            //Cluster Activation 
            ignite.cluster().active(true);
            LOGGER.info("IGNITE CACHE STARTED");
        } catch (IgniteException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw e;
        }

    }
    public IgniteCache<String, Integer> getOrCreateCache(String name){

        return  ignite.getOrCreateCache(name);

    }
}
```

Here igniteProperties.getproperties is the cacheconfig.xml file which the DiscoverySpi and cache expiry configurations.
To add the server the to cluster whether i have to make any other changes.
Please help on this.

Below is my cache configuration used while starting the ignite

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">
    <bean abstract="true" id="ignite.cfg"
        class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">

        <!-- Set to true to enable distributed class loading for examples, default 
            is false. -->
        <!-- <property name="clientMode" value="true"/> -->
        <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true" />
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="hcache" />
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <!-- <bean id="expiryPolicy" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy" 
                            factory-method="factoryOf"> -->
                        <bean id="expiryPolicy" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy"
                            factory-method="factoryOf">
                            <!-- CreatedExpiryPolicy is used to inform the cache provider to remove 
                                the entry after a specified time since the entry’s addition to the cache. -->
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                    <constructor-arg value="HOURS" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="1" />

                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="dcache" />
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <bean id="expiryPolicy" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy"
                            factory-method="factoryOf">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                    <constructor-arg value="HOURS" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="24" />
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="wcache" />
                    <property name="expiryPolicyFactory">
                        <bean id="expiryPolicy" class="javax.cache.expiry.CreatedExpiryPolicy"
                            factory-method="factoryOf">
                            <constructor-arg>
                                <bean class="javax.cache.expiry.Duration">
                                    <constructor-arg value="DAYS" />
                                    <constructor-arg value="7" />
                                </bean>
                            </constructor-arg>
                        </bean>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>

        <!-- Enable task execution events for examples. -->
        <property name="includeEventTypes">
            <list>
                <!--Task execution events -->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_STARTED" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FINISHED" />
                <!-- This event is triggered every time a task finished with an exception -->
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_FAILED" />

                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_TIMEDOUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_SESSION_ATTR_SET" />
                <util:constant static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_TASK_REDUCED" />

                <!--Cache events -->
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_PUT" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_READ" />
                <util:constant
                    static-field="org.apache.ignite.events.EventType.EVT_CACHE_OBJECT_REMOVED" />

            </list>
        </property>
        <!-- <property name="eagerTtl" value="true" /> -->
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                    <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                        <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>

        <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial 
            nodes. -->
            <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="ipFinder">
                    <!-- Ignite provides several options for automatic discovery that can 
                        be used instead os static IP based discovery. For information on all options 
                        refer to our documentation: http://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config -->
                    <!-- Uncomment static IP finder to enable static-based discovery of 
                        initial nodes. -->
                    <!--<bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder"> -->
                    <bean
                        class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.multicast.TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                                <!-- <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value> -->
                                <value>server1</value>
                                <value>server2</value>
                                <value>server3</value>
                                <value>server4</value>
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use other [discovery mechanisms](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/cluster-config#section-apache-jclouds-based-discovery) if you don't want to maintain a long list of addresses.

You also don't have to list every IP in this section. Once node finds even one server from the list, it will know about all other nodes in cluster automatically.

Comment: I m new to ignite. I tried in the same way given in the this example(with multicast IPFinder)
" https://github.com/apache/ignite/blob/master/modules/clients/src/test/resources/spring-cache.xml "

I understood like to add the server ip's into cluster we should give this way.

Is there any way to add the servers into the cluster via xml itself.

Comment: @sri you can specify servers in the Tcp IP Finder: https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/spi/discovery/tcp/ipfinder/vm/TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder.html

Answer (score 0):

In the example that you have provided, there's several problems, as far as my understanding goes:

`<value>158.xxx.xx.xxx</value>` - this line should have port or ports range.
`<value>4444</value>` - you can't supply port on additional line, you should list it with addresses.
`<value>158.xxx.xx.xxx:4444..158.xxx.xx.xxx:4444</value>` - You can have ports range, but you can't have IP address range in that fashion.

```
   <property name="addresses">
      <list>
        <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
        <value>158.xxx.xx.xxx:47500..47509</value><!--server1 ip-->
        <value>158.xxx.xx.xxx:47500..47509</value><!--server2 ip-->
        <value>158.xxx.xx.xxx:47500..47509</value><!--server3 ip-->
      </list>
    </property>
```

I don't recommend changing default ports if you're a newbie, since it will require changing other settings, your objective should be getting basic clustering to work.

This configuration should work for clusters of any number of nodes, provided that server 1, 2 or 3 have at least one node running. The rest of nodes will be found via discovery.

Comment: how my one server will find the other server and cluster with it unless and until i mention it somewhere in my configuration file

Comment: Once your server will find e.g. server1, it will immediately know about all servers in cluster, and they will all know about that server.

Comment: It will know only when i have mentioned those IP's under my discoverySpi
am i right?

Comment: Nope! All nodes in cluster know about all other nodes in cluster, regards of discoverySpi settings. Node doesn't have to be in the list to join.

Comment: How do i add the nodes to the cluster?
I m starting my ignite using example-ignite.xml file.
In my higher environment i have BIGVIP under servers will be listed.
I need to share my cache across 4 servers.

Comment: i have updated the spring boot+java code i m using for ignite to start and cluster it.Please check whether i need to make any other code level change for clustering to happen.

Comment: @sri I don't see that you have updated your config snippets. Please do.

Comment: added cache configuration file please help on this

Comment: added cache configuration file please help on this

Comment: You have all IPs in Discovery SPI compound in one line, this is incorrect. Please do as shown above.

Comment: Please update your ticket with correct configuration with all incorrect fragments removed, so that we can take a look at what is still wrong.

Comment: Even i tried both(giving in one line and separate) are working as same.I could cluster only two.Other 2 servers starts individually.
(Expected: If i m posting some value in server1 and i could be able fetch from server2,3,4.)

Comment: but while giving in different line it works without giving the port as separate value.But only 1st and the 4th server are getting clustered.

Comment: I am now very confused by your descriptions, so I suggest you to overhaul your post while looking at the docs with one eye.

Comment: please check now?

Comment: @sri Can you provide logs? Did you specify port? Do you have single node per IP address?

Comment: same port for all ip.
Do you have single node per IP address? this i m not getting.
Here i m trying to put 4 ip's with same port into a cluster

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SNUtMUF6kkvWXCrJ7xG5lVcMuX4ygtevaxqHTcDomnE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Unfortunately, these tiny snippets are not enough. Can you provide full node logs? Preferably with `-DIGNITE_QUIET=false`

Comment: Server_1_logs
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SNUtMUF6kkvWXCrJ7xG5lVcMuX4ygtevaxqHTcDomnE/edit?usp=sharing
Server_2_logs
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1blgF_BMyU3FSb3D6mwo-jg12DXzPRbaUE9Cu1ThxyLY/edit?usp=sharing
Server_3_logs
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TNmdSt3uRpE3wP9IH7FFgSBdVImOPys-YvH8amhYoIQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: These logs look OK, no reason to see this behaviour. I would think that either there's no connectivity between server_2 and server 1 and 3, or incorrect list of hosts in their discovery finders. I'll check later whether BLT could cause something like that.

Comment: host names are correct.. Because I m able to load and fetch values from each server separately.But cache sharing is not happening across servers

Comment: That you're able to connect to all 3 servers doesn't mean that they have connectivity between them. Yes, I can see that you basically have two clusters there.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this scenario in lab setting.

Comment: i checked. Firewall exist across all 3 servers.

Comment: whether my cache mandatory tp be "partitioned cache" to act as a distributed cache?

Comment: @sri if you have new questions, please ask them using "Ask Question" button.